# Have error "android.os.FileUriExposedException" with CanHub Image Cropper

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an error while using CanHub Image Cropper to create a crop activity.

Here is my code

```
private val cropImage = registerForActivityResult(CropImageContract()) { result ->
    if (result.isSuccessful) {
        // Use the returned uri.
        val uriContent = result.uriContent
        val uriFilePath = result.getUriFilePath(requireContext()) // optional usage
    } else {
        // An error occurred.
        val exception = result.error
    }
}

private fun startCrop() {
    val cropImageOptions = CropImageOptions()
    cropImageOptions.imageSourceIncludeGallery = true
    cropImageOptions.imageSourceIncludeCamera = true
    val cropImageContractOptions = CropImageContractOptions(null, cropImageOptions)
    cropImage.launch(cropImageContractOptions)
}
```

Here is the stacktrace

```
android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///data/user/0/android.buiducha.translateapp/cache/tmp_image_file2596572382203291616.png exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
                                                                                                    at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:2141)
                                                                                                    at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2391)
                                                                                                    at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:964)
                                                                                                    at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:11119)
                                                                                                    at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:11104)
                                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1722)
                                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5314)
                                                                                                    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:754)
                                                                                                    at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat$Api16Impl.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:860)
                                                                                                    at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:249)
                                                                                                    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$2.onLaunch(ComponentActivity.java:258)
                                                                                                    at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$2.launch(ActivityResultRegistry.java:175)
                                                                                                    at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher.launch(ActivityResultLauncher.java:47)
                                                                                                    at com.canhub.cropper.CropImageActivity.openCamera(CropImageActivity.kt:175)
                                                                                                    at com.canhub.cropper.CropImageActivity.openSource(CropImageActivity.kt:167)
                                                                                                    at com.canhub.cropper.CropImageActivity.access$openSource(CropImageActivity.kt:32)
                                                                                                    at com.canhub.cropper.CropImageActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(CropImageActivity.kt:73)
                                                                                                    at com.canhub.cropper.CropImageActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(CropImageActivity.kt:73)
                                                                                                    at com.canhub.cropper.CropImageActivity.showImageSourceDialog$lambda$16(CropImageActivity.kt:208)
                                                                                                    at com.canhub.cropper.CropImageActivity.$r8$lambda$dzoPeA2CRMlvXJjZcsgHCnb2qwg(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                    at com.canhub.cropper.CropImageActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
                                                                                                    at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:1068)
                                                                                                    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:330)
                                                                                                    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1187)
                                                                                                    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3179)
                                                                                                    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4097)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Based on the error, I think it occurred because I passed a null value to CropImageContractOptions. However, I have no idea what to pass into this, and I only get an error when I use the camera to take a picture.

Comment: `think it occurred because I passed a null value ` No it clearly states that there is a file uri exposed exception. Google as this was already solved for Android 7.

Comment: I tried to Google it, but I still have no idea how to fix that error. I tried to add a provider into a manifest file, but nothing changed. I also passed a URI into CropImageContractsOptions, but it still doesn't work